'RNPkceChallenceSpec.h' file not found
Having some trouble with a react library in the latest version of React native, I've raised a issue on the library and started looking into it myself but haven't got anywhere.
The GH issue i created can be seen here with steps to reproduce and a screenshot: https://github.com/dcangulo/react-native-pkce-challenge/issues/508
